# explicit Intent to start new activity automatically after a splash screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I am still pretty new to this and I am working on my first app. The problem I am having is this.

I have a splash screen that is working fine, but I keep getting an error when it goes to switch to a new activity. I know the problem is in the intent, but I don't know what it is or how to fix it. My code is:

```
 splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        synchronized(this){

                            //wait 5 sec
                            wait(_splashTime);
                        }

                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                    finally {
                        finish();

                        //start a new activity

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MAIN.this, Home.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                        stop();
```

and the cat log is:

```
02-12 13:01:46.009: D/AndroidRuntime(753): Shutting down VM
02-12 13:01:46.009: W/dalvikvm(753): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.madonk.LAFEST/com.madonk.LAFEST.Home}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:241)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1716)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.madonk.LAFEST.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  ... 11 more
```

Home Activity

```
package com.madonk.LAFEST;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Home extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your home activity is the troublemaker. Post the code from your Home.class plz

Comment: it can't be the Home activity because I have changed nothing in it. it calls up the xml file and thats it.

Comment: That's odd. Cause this line here says different:
"02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.madonk.LAFEST/com.madonk.LAFEST.Home}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout"

Comment: Look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
Your implementation of ListView is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seem you use ListActivity . The [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) of ListActivity says

> you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

check up the res/layout/home.xml in your project. base your exception I believe you put that id in your LinearLayout , so **move your "@android:id/list" from LinearLayout to ListView**. or post your home.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Home.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
```

The docs say:

> Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls) Create an intent for a
>   specific component.

You missed to put your context into the Intent.

You can read more about Intents here:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

and here:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

And here is a nice tutorial about Intents:

> http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

You really should read through the tutorial. It helped me alot!

Edit: You are calling finish() and stop(). Calling finish() will call your onDestroy(). I'm not sure what happens, when you call stop() afte having called finish(). You should delete your call for stop().

Comment: its giving me an error now, it says: the constructor Intent(new Thread(){}, Class<Home>) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Based on these two lines:

```
02-12 13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout 02-12
13:01:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:241)
```

I'm willing to bet that R.layout.home is a LinearLayout, not a ListActivity.

As well, this line specifically points at the `setContentView` call:

```
at com.madonk.LAFEST.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
```